# WebElelement = null in the same class

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I'm trying to test a dialog but for some reason I'm getting WebElement = null.

In test:

```
DomainActions da = new DomainActions();

...
da.fillUserNoteFieldDeleteDomainPopUp(propAP.getPropertiesValues("deleteDomainUserNote"));
da.clickDeleteButtonDeletePopUp();

...
```

Method called from DomainActions:

```
    @Step("Fill 'User Note' Field in 'Delete domain' Popup")
    public boolean fillUserNoteFieldDeleteDomainPopUp(String UserNoteInDeletePopUp) {

        return pageObj.fillEditFieldOnDialog(userNoteDeleteDomainField, UserNoteInDeletePopUp,
                "'User Note' Field in 'Delete domain' Popup is filled" );
    }
```

When method is called "userNoteDeleteDomainField" is already equal null.

Object in this class is added as:

```
    @Name("'User Note' - 'Delete domain' PopUp - Field")
    @Visible
    @FindBy(xpath = "//app-form-field[2]/div/div/textarea")
    private static WebElement userNoteDeleteDomainField;
```

I understand that if method is boolean I should check returned value.
I will do that in next step.
First I need to fill this field.

**Do you know what am I doing wrong?**

[image]

Comment: What is `pageObj`? Where do you initialize it?

Comment: It's a class for handling general objects like click a button, select check box... Object of this class is initialized before all web elements in DomainAction class. But I'm not even going there. I'm getting a null before return pageObj.fill...(I think so)